# Ansible conditional with variables and wildcards

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

Been trying to add a conditional with a wildcard and an Ansible variable and getting an error message. The idea is to trigger the api request with the container name starts with "android-", this is a follow-up to a docker container creation playbook.

My playbook:

```
---
- name: move agent android
  hosts: server1; server2
  vars:
    containers: "{{ containers }}" #variable in a different file

tasks:
    - name: move agent Android
      command: curl "api request to a server"
      when:  "containers.startswith('android-*')"
```

the error:

```
TASK [move agent Android] ******************************************************
  fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'containers.startswith('android-*')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (containers.startswith('android-*')): 'list object' has no attribute 'startswith'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/directory/were/the/playbook/is/move-agent-android.yml': line 13, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: move agent Android\n      ^ here\n"}
I have tried to change the conditionals to different versions and all gething the same error.
```

other versions:

```
    when:  "containers is match('android-*')"
    
    when:  item.name.startswith('android-*')
    
    when:  "{{ containers }}" is match('android-*')

    when: containers.name is match('^android-*')
```

Any idea how to solve the error?

Comment: Your var containers is a list object, the lists don't have the `startswith` method. That method would require a strings. Same issue with the `is match`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample of playbook: use loop, i suppose containers is a list of name of containers, if its dict you adapt item.name or other....

```
- name: move agent android
  hosts: server1; server2
  vars:
    containers: "{{ containers }}" #variable in a different file

tasks:
    - name: move agent Android
      command: curl "api request to a server"
      when:  item.startswith('android-')
      loop: "{{ containers }}"
```